# Using jquery CascadingDropDown with jquery selectbox

Tags: jquery, cascadingdropdown, jquery-selectbox

How can I use jquery CascadingDropDown together with jquery selectbox ?

Comment: I know you asked this question in order to answer it yourself, but you still need to write questions that are *possible* for others to answer. As it is, your question is too vague and lacks any "what have you tried" code which shows us what you need fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To use jquery CascadingDropDown along with jquery selectbox plugin you need to detach and attach after load and reset events in cascadeded dropdowns :

Make following changes in jquery.cascadingDropDown.js :

```
reset: function () {
    methods.clearItems();
    $this.append($(optionTag)
        .attr("value", "")
        .text(config.promptText));
    $this.trigger('change');
    if ($this.attr('sb') != undefined) {
        $this.selectbox('detach');
        $this.selectbox('attach');
    }
},
```

and

```
loaded: function () {
    $this.removeAttr("disabled");
    $this.trigger('change');
    if ($this.attr('sb') != undefined) {
        $this.selectbox('detach');
        $this.selectbox('attach');
    }
},
```

Hope it helps